# How to set image source in WPF programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set an image source in WPF but relative Uri doesn't work.

```
imgView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Res/Images/img.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

But this works:

```
imgView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("E:/C#/Folder/Project/Res/Images/img.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

What should I change in relative Uri?

Comment: Set the Build Action of the image file to Resource. Then use a full resource file Pack URI: `imgView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Res/Images/img.png"));`

Comment: Thanks, this works

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Build Action` of the image to `Content` and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`.

This should ensure that it's copied to the output directory of the `.exe` (typically `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release`) when you build. 
The the path is relative to the `.exe` and not to the project.

The other option would be to set the `Build Action` to `Resource`, which is the default value, and use a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) to specify the path.